# How to use a makefile when calling MATLAB functions in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, unix, gcc, makefile

I have been struggling with getting an application I am modifying to compile when I attempt to call MATLAB functions inside it. I was able to download and run the engdemo.c which demonstrates the use of MATLAB in C++, however trying to extend what I was able to learn from this demo I cannot seem to get things to compile. I think one problem is that I have a makefile, and I am unsure of where to put a line to tell GCC where the MATLAB libraries are. It seems others have struggled implementing connections to MATLAB using makefiles as well, so I hope that this question may be of some use.

Some relevant information:

- I am using Fedora
- I am using GCC 4.9.2
- I am using MATLAB R2015b

Here is my makefile so far:

```
    EXECUTABLE:= ../bin/linux/ccmd 

intel: CC = icpc
intel: LD = icpc

gnu: CC = g++
gnu: LD = g++

C_SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
CXX_SRCS := $(wildcard *.cpp)
# program_CU_SRCS := $(wildcard *.cu)
C_OBJS := ${C_SRCS:.c=.o}
CXX_OBJS := ${CXX_SRCS:.cpp=.o}
# program_CU_OBJS := ${program_CU_SRCS:.cu=.o}
OBJS := $(C_OBJS) $(CXX_OBJS)

BUILD_DIR := ../build/linux/
OBJS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR), $(OBJS))
VPATH = ./ 

BOOST_INCLUDE = /u/tps/crennick/boost_1_55_0

# root directory of MATLAB installation
MATLABROOT="/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64"

intel: INCLUDE_DIRS := $(BOOST_INCLUDE) $(MATLABROOT) ./include
gnu: INCLUDE_DIRS :=  ./include $(MATLABROOT)

intel: LIBRARY_DIR := -L/u/tps/crennick/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/
LIBRARIES := -lboost_system-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lpthread -lpng -lz -d -leng /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so

CPPFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))

intel: CPPFLAGS += -O3 -std=c++11
#gnu: CPPFLAGS += -Ofast -std=c++11 -march=native -ffast-math -flto
#gnu: LDFLAGS += -Ofast -std=c++11 -march=native -ffast-math -flto
gnu: CPPFLAGS += -Ofast -std=c++11  -march=native -ffast-math -flto -m64 -funroll-loops
gnu: LDFLAGS += -Ofast -std=c++11 -march=native -ffast-math -flto -m64 -funroll-loops
gnu: CPPFLAGS = -std=c++11 -g
gnu: LDFLAGS = -std=c++11

#LIBRARY_PATH = $(foreach librarydir,$(LIBRARIES),$(librarydir))

.PHONY: all clean distclean

gnu: $(EXECUTABLE)
intel: $(EXECUTABLE)

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS)
#   ar rc $@ $^  
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBRARY_DIR) $(LIBRARIES)

$(BUILD_DIR)%.o : %.cpp 
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CPPFLAGS)

# $(BUILD_DIR)bodysystemcuda.o: bodysystemcuda.cu bodysystemcuda.cpp include/bodysystemcuda.h
#   $(NVCC_PATH)/nvcc -O3 --include-path $(CUTIL_LIB) -c bodysystemcuda.cu -o $(BUILD_DIR)bodysystemcuda.o 

clean:
    @- $(RM) $(EXECUTABLE)
    @- $(RM) $(OBJS)


distclean: clean
```

Here are the errors I receive on compilation:

```
    /usr/bin/ld: warning: libmwresource_core.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmwi18n.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libut.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmwfl.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_date_time.so.1.49.0, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_filesystem.so.1.49.0, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_log.so.1.49.0, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_signals.so.1.49.0, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.49.0, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_thread.so.1.49.0, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmwcpp11compat.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicudata.so.54, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicuuc.so.54, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicui18n.so.54, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicuio.so.54, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmx.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libhdf5_hl.so.8, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libhdf5.so.8, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
../build/linux/image.o: In function `Image::conv_1D(double*, int, double*, int)':
```

Here's what I've tried:

- Typing the directories of each library demanded exactly (inefficient, threw the same errors anyway)
- Attempted using wildcards to include all libraries in the directory /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64. Seems wasteful, also throws errors
- As can be seen in the code I included, I have tried to include the MATLABROOT directory inside the INCLUDE_DIRS section where I expected the compiler would want it. This did not fix anything either.

Thank you for your assistance, I hope that maybe this question will help others also be able to build C++ applications that call MATLAB functions using makefiles as well, especialy if they are like me and don't have a good grasp of GCC/UNIX/Makefiles!

Comment: Those are all warnings (but you should fix them, probably by adding `-rpath $(MATLABROOT)` to your link line or get that path into the normal system library path). The error you get would be just below the last line in that snippet. What is it?

Comment: Thanks, that helps! The errors bellow that line are all saying that the MATLAB functions I am trying to call are undefined. Here's an example: undefined reference to `engOpen' and undefined reference to `mxCreateDoubleMatrix' that I figured would be resolved as soon as I got the makefile pointing the compiler to the right directory.

Comment: Where do those functions come from? What library? `libmat.so`? Something else?

Comment: They come from libmat.so and libmx.so exclusively. I have taken a screenshot: http://imgur.com/rZXAjf6

Comment: Oh, the libraries themselves are reporting missing references. Where do all of those functions/etc. listed as undefined come from? What library is supposed to provide them? The order of libraries matters. You need the library that *uses* the symbol listed *before* the library the provides it.